# assign values of nested dict to list in python

Tags: json, python-3.x, dictionary, nested

I have file that is list of JSON objects. It looks like this :

```
[
  {
    "id": 748,
    "location": {
      "slug": "istanbul",
      "parent": {
        "id": 442,
        "slug": "turkey"
      }
    },
    "rank": 110
  },
  {
    "id": 769,
    "location": {
      "slug": "dubai",
      "parent": {
        "id": 473,
        "slug": "uae"
      }
    },
    "rank": 24
  }
]
```

I want to create a list of hotel parent names, so i write this code to do this, I read the JSON file and assigned it to a variable, that part is correct. But look at this code :

```
with open('hotels.json', 'r', encoding="utf8") as hotels_data:
    hotels = json.load(hotels_data)

parents_list = []
for item in hotels:
    if item["location"]["parent"]["slug"] not in parents_list:
        parents_list.append(item["location"]["parent"])
```

when i run this code, i give this error :

```
if item["location"]["parent"]["slug"] not in parents_list:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

This code does not work, so I tried to print the JSON objects so I wrote this in the loop:

```
print(item["location"]["parent"]["slug"])
```

This code prints the values I want, but also give me the exact same error. 
thank you for any help.

Comment: Does this code fail with the given sample data?

Comment: are you using python3 or python2?

Comment: i'm using python 3.6

Comment: The problem seems not to occur in the data you posted. Can you upload the json file somewhere and add the link to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried running the code and it seems to be working fine with your dataset.

However, instead of opening the file to read the data, I just assigned hotels with your dataset, `hotels = [...]`.

The result I got was this:

```
[{'id': 442, 'slug': 'turkey'}, {'id': 473, 'slug': 'uae'}]
```

What is your result if you print `hotels`, is it the same as you shown here?

---

If you actually have a lot more data in your dataset, then I can presume that some of the dictionaries don't contain `item["location"]["parent"]["slug"]`.  If that is the case, you should skip those by checking if that element exists in each `item` first before reading off from the `parents_list`.

For example:

```
try:
    item["location"]["parent"]["slug"]
except (KeyError, TypeError) as e:
    pass
else:
    if item["location"]["parent"]["slug"] not in parents_list:
        parents_list.append(item["location"]["parent"])
```

Comment: I got the same array when I was testing the OPs code

Comment: well it fixed now but i had to check all levels of dict like this:  `if item["location"]:
                if item["location"]["parent"]:
                    if item["location"]["parent"]["slug"]:
                        if item["location"]["parent"]["slug"] not in parents_list:
                            parents_list.append(item["location"]["parent"]["slug"])` is there a better way for this check ?

Comment: @Amirition My apologies, use `try` and `else` as I have suggested in my answer.

Comment: It gives me the same error in line `item["location"]["parent"]["slug"]` with your suggested code.

Comment: @Amirition My example code is working fine.  Empty dictionary passes as KeyError.  Make sure that you have the correct indentation, especially the `if` line.  What is your full error message?

Comment: The indentation is correct. this is the error: `item["location"]["parent"]["slug"]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: @Amirition I was able to replicate the problem.  I have updated my answer to catch both `KeyError` and `TypeError`

Answer (score -1):

I cannot replicate the same error as you. The only thing that I can think of is that the last item in each object in the JSON shouldn't have a comma after it. See if that fixes your error

Comment: yeah that was a mistake i made while i was writing the question, i corrected it.

Comment: it was actually a problem in the file. it's ok now. thanks .